# I am trying to traverse the file structure in Breadth first fashion. I am getting segmentation violation

Tags: go, recursion

I know about `ioutil.ReadDir` and `os.filePath` but none of them traverse the directory in Breadth first fashion. 
My approach is to call `ioutil.ReadDir` and append all the contents of the root dir into a slice. Then I am iterating over the contents and checking if it `IsDir[]` and calling the function recursively if true.

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

var files []string
var path string

func appendFiles(root string) {
    fileInfo, err := ioutil.ReadDir(root)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for _, file := range fileInfo {
        files = append(files, file.Name())
    }

    for _, file := range fileInfo {
        fileStat, _ := os.Stat(file.Name())
        if fileStat.Mode().IsDir() {
            // path = path + "/" + file.Name()
            appendFiles(file.Name())
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    appendFiles(".")
}
```

Comment: Please quote the actual output you get when running the program, see also [ask]. Concerning your code, make sure it is a [mcve]. As a new user, also take the [tour].

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`os.Stat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stat) may return an `error` which you omit. When that happens, `fileStat` may be `nil`, so calling `fileStat.Mode()` in the next line panics.

And the reason `os.Stat()` fails is because `file.Name()` is relative to `root`, `file.Name()` by itself has little chance to exist, it must be joined with `root`. If `os.Stat()` is called with a file name that doesn't exist, it returns a `nil` file info and a non-`nil` error.

You may use [`filepath.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join) to construct a valid path for files that `os.Stat()` will work with. And it would be better to handle errors, e.g. return them, which you can inspect in `main()`.

```
func appendFiles(root string) error {
    fileInfo, err := ioutil.ReadDir(root)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("ReadDir error: %w", err)
    }
    for _, file := range fileInfo {
        files = append(files, filepath.Join(root, file.Name()))
    }

    for _, file := range fileInfo {
        fullName := filepath.Join(root, file.Name())
        fileStat, err := os.Stat(fullName)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Stat error: %w", err)
        }
        if fileStat.Mode().IsDir() {
            if err := appendFiles(fullName); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("appendFiles error: %w", err)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    if err := appendFiles("."); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```